# Can someone explain the following NFA?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I'm learning NFA and the following question is confusing me.

[image]

Can Someone explain the answer. I have a feeling that it might be wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a bit more details on what are you confused about?

Comment: If I take a string '00100010'. The given NFA doesn't satisfy the second condition.

Comment: The string 00100010 is in your language and is also accepted by the NFA. Here is the sequence of states of an accepting path: $q_1$ (initial state), $q_1, q_1, q_1, q_1, q_1, q_1, q_2$, $q_3$ (using the $\varepsilon$-transition), $q_A$.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question to make clear what question you are asking.  Similarly, we prefer that answers be placed in the 'Your Answer' box below rather than in the comments.  Thank you!